# Active Directory Limited Admin for Moodle LDAP integration

Tags: active-directory, ldap, moodle

I have Moodle which I already integrated to Active Directory (LDAP). The integration needs user for binding (To authenticate users).
I want to limit that user because its currently member of Domain Admin, the Moodle site will not write anything back to the server, it will only read the objects.
in Short, what is the best user security scenario that works with Moodle and has no write privilege?